# Local Sql express 2 way sync to remote server

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, sql-server-express

i have a native windows application (software) with a local sqlexpress database. I need to bring the data from every local install (5000 in number) to central server which would be mysql. 
1./ I don't think i will be able to do port forwards etc on the router at every local installation and hence wonder what's the best way to get the synchronization done. 
2./ At the central server should i use ms sql instead. Is there a compelling reason to stick to ms sql at central level?

regards
Ravz

Answer (score 1):

> At the central server should i use ms sql instead

Yes, and not the free version.

You could then use some sort of replication.

> Is there a compelling reason to stick to ms sql at central level?

You MUST be joking. Read the documentation. SQL Server has some really nice features in the non free versions for that - replication for example. The last time we tried setting this up (laptops, was ages ago) we went with transactional replication between sql servers and it worked like a charm.

Alternatively you can sit down and start writing. There is a db agnostic sync fraemwork available, or you can totally roll your own - both valid approaches. But you should really check first what you can do.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Replication

You can use transactional replication and use the expres editions as subscribers against a central master database.

Comment: the sql server solution would be way more expensive than a mysql one,hence asking. Just how bad is it to have mysql at central level and are there any tools available?

Comment: Well, no replication? Gratulations to that saved money - takes likely a LOT of time to program that, which is 0 if your time is not worth anything. THe edges can run SQL Epress which is free anyway.